# DateTime Unspecified Kind

Tags: c#, datetime

[On msdn it is defined for Unspecified Kind as:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> [image: kind]

So if Kind is unspecified DateTime is UTC, but on the same page (given example):

```
class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
      DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;
      myDt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(saveNow, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
      Display("Unspecified: .....", myDt);
    }

    public static string datePatt = @"M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";

    public static void Display(string title, DateTime inputDt)
    {
      DateTime dispDt = inputDt;
      string dtString;
    
      dtString = dispDt.ToString(datePatt);
      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}, Kind = {2}", title, dtString, dispDt.Kind);

      dispDt = inputDt.ToLocalTime();
      dtString = dispDt.ToString(datePatt);
      Console.WriteLine("  ToLocalTime:     {0}, Kind = {1}", dtString, dispDt.Kind);

      dispDt = inputDt.ToUniversalTime();
      dtString = dispDt.ToString(datePatt);
      Console.WriteLine("  ToUniversalTime: {0}, Kind = {1}", dtString, dispDt.Kind);
      Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }
}
```

giving the output as:

> Unspecified: ..... 5/6/2005 02:34:42 PM, Kind = Unspecified
>
> ToLocalTime:     5/6/2005 07:34:42 AM, Kind = Local
>
> ToUniversalTime: 5/6/2005 09:34:42 PM, Kind = Utc

So, issue I have with this is, that if Unspecified is Utc then why Utc to Utc conversion change the datetime object value?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

No, Unspecified and UTC are very different - the page you're quoting from is from `ToLocalTime`. The point is that if you call `ToLocalTime` using an "unspecified" `DateTime`, then the value will be treated *as if* it were in UTC.

Likewise if you call `ToUniversalTime` using an "unspecified" `DateTime`, then the value will be treated *as if* it were in the system local time zone.

Frankly this sort of thing is why [I dislike `DateTime` rather a lot](https://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html). If I were you, I'd use [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) instead, which separates the concepts out into different types entirely, removing a lot of the confusion. (There are more types to know about, but each one represents a single concept.) I'm clearly biased though...

Comment: @PawelKrakowiak: Gosh, what an old post... updated both the project URL and the one for the blog.

Comment: old but still valid? @JonSkeet

Comment: @Jean-Paul: All of this is still valid as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Isn't this a little bit weird? Treating an object differently depending on what method you call on it.

Comment: @eddyP23: I'm not sure what you mean by "treating an object differently depending on what method you call on it" - it's more that the method behaves differently depending on the state inside the value.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am talking about `Kind.Unspecified`. Calling on a `DateTime` object method `ToLocalTime()` it assumes that the time is in UTC, but calling `ToUtcTime()` it assumes the time is in local timezone.

Comment: @eddyP23: I think that's defensible as "if we don't know any better, let's assume that the call you're making is a useful one". But it's definitely part of the fall-out of the mess of having a single type represent multiple different things.

Comment: Arrggh, thanks. Dates are like character encodings - you think you know enough until something doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

The DateTimeKind.Unspecified is useful in cases where you don't want the time to be converted to another local time.

Take for example a server application which displays the current time for the server in a client application.  If you do not specify DateTimeKind.Unspecified on the server and the current time is retrieved through a WCF call, then when .ToString is called in the client application, it will automatically be converted to the local time zone if they are different.